# What is the functor of points of the moduli scheme of stable sheaves?

Tags: sheaf-theory, moduli-spaces, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $\Bbbk$ be an algebraic closed field of characteristic zero. Let $(\mathrm{Sch}/\Bbbk$ denote the category of locally Noetherian schemes. Let $B$ be a projective scheme over $\Bbbk$. Let $L$ be an ample line bundle on $B$. Let $P(t)\in \mathbb Q[t]$ be a Hilbert polynomial. Let $M^{\mathrm{s}}$ denote the moduli scheme of stable sheaves of Hilbert polynomial $P(t)$ on $B$. It is the coarse moduli space of the following functor
\begin{equation}
\mathbf M^{\mathrm{s}}:(\mathrm{Sch}/\Bbbk)^{\mathrm{op}}\to \mathrm{Set},\quad T\mapsto\Big\{\begin{matrix}\textrm{flat families over }T\textrm{ such that fibres at closed }t\in T\\
\textrm{are stable sheaves on }B\textrm{ of Hilbert polynomial }P(t)\end{matrix}\Big\}\Big/\sim
\end{equation}
where a *flat family over $T$* is a coherent sheaf $\mathcal F$ on $B_T:=B\times_\Bbbk T$ that is flat over $T$, and the equivalence relation $\sim$ above is
\begin{equation}
\mathcal F\sim \mathcal F'\iff\mathcal F'\cong \mathcal F\otimes_{\mathcal O_{B_T}}(B_T\to T)^*\mathcal A\textrm{ for some line bundle }\mathcal A \textrm{ on }T. 
\end{equation}
A good reference for the context is Huybrechts' *The geometry of moduli spaces of sheaves*. The moduli scheme $M^{\mathrm{s}}$ was first contructed by Simpson using geometric invariant theory of reductive groups. The construction are described in Huybrechts' book.

There is natural transformation $\mathbf M^{\mathrm{s}}\to M^{\mathrm{s}}$. It turns out to be surjective after sheafification in $(\mathrm{Sch}/\Bbbk)_{\acute etale}$: We have that $M^{\mathrm{s}}\cong R^{\mathrm{s}}/\mathrm{PGL}(N)$ is a geometric quotient for some action $\mathrm{PGL}(N)\curvearrowright R^{\mathrm{s}}$, which is a principal bundle by Corollary 4.3.5 in Huybrechts'. Moreover the quotient morphism $R^{\mathrm{s}}\to M^{\mathrm{s}}$ factors through the moduli functor $\mathbf M^{\mathrm{s}}$. This proves $(\mathbf M^{\mathrm{s}})^\sharp\to M^{\mathrm{s}}$ is surjective between étale sheaves, where ${}^\sharp$ indicates the sheafification.

It is also possible to construct a morphism $M^{\mathrm{s}}\to (\mathbf M^{\mathrm{s}})^\sharp$, which is induced by $M^{\mathrm{s}}\dashrightarrow R^{\mathrm{s}}\to \mathbf M^{\mathrm{s}}\to (\mathbf M^{\mathrm{s}})^\sharp$, where $M^{\mathrm{s}}\dashrightarrow R^{\mathrm{s}}$ exists étale locally as a section of $R^{\mathrm{s}}\to M^{\mathrm{s}}$.

My question is:

> Are these two morphisms $M^{\mathrm{s}}\to (\mathbf M^{\mathrm{s}})^\sharp$ and $(\mathbf M^{\mathrm{s}})^\sharp\to M^{\mathrm{s}}$ inverse to each other?

If so why people prefer $\mathbf M^{\mathrm{s}}$ than $(\mathbf M^{\mathrm{s}})^\sharp$ as the moduli functor?